# How long is Orthodox Conversion?

Tags: time, conversion-to-judaism, orthodox

How long is the conversion process into Traditional Orthodox and Modern Orthodox? What is the minimum time period in most cases? I know converts can spend years preparing until they actually finalise their conversion.

Comment: I suspect this is highly variable.  I've heard of people completing the process in a year or two, and of ones who spent ten or more years on it.  There are lots of variables.

Comment: i have heard from 6 months (someone who had already lived for 20 years as a conservadox jew and then found out that a maternal great-grandmother wasn't actually jewish) to 2 years. part may be the level of background, how knowledgable the prospective convert is when he starts the process, how much time he commits to the life changes or the learning early on etc.

Comment: "Minimum time" in "most cases"? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I know someone who took over 5 years...

Comment: A friend of mine who was fully observant found out he wasn't Jewish, and converted within a week.

Comment: When I converted 32 years ago, I already had a Conservative conversion from 2 years earlier, and therefore more background than somene beginning, and it still took a year.  But another did it in 10 months.  I find that most rabbis want you to go a year to experience all f the holidays.  More importantly, they want you to know enough to realize how little you know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Rabbinical Council of America (RCA) [conversion FAQ](http://www.judaismconversion.org/faq.html):

> The amount of time for a convert to be prepared for conversion varies
>   from case to case, depending upon the level of knowledge and
>   experience that preceded the quest for conversion and many other
>   factors. A minimum of two years of study and experiential growth is
>   generally recommended though individual circumstances may vary in this
>   regard. During this time, the candidate will be in communication with
>   the Beit Din to review his or her progress, and make any necessary
>   adjustments or decisions as to the remaining course of study and
>   personal growth.

Answer (score 0):

No specified time is usually minimum is one (1) year. But this can vary, it depends on the person who will become. Study the Torah, Talmud and other sacred books is important, and more than that, is to practice, the practice is essential. But all of rabbinic monitoring.

Comment: Usually one year, is that specified in the Halacha?

Comment: Shmuel, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the answer! Do you have a particular source for this statement? Personal experience? Experience from others you have seen/helped? MY places a lot of emphasis on sources (after all most of us don’t know you personally)

Comment: Also if you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Talvez não completamente ler o meu comentário. Não tenho a pretensão de ser um (1) ano, eu disse que é normalmente pelo menos um (1). E porque ? Porque a maioria dos candidatos que optam por seguir o judaísmo já estão bem familiarizados com a religião. Mas eu acredito que em menos de um (1) uma pessoa não é convertido. Portanto, este período é o mínimo do mínimo.
At least the Orthodox court of my city requires this period at least. But everything depends on the person.